# How to remove blank space from website?

Tags: html, css

You can view the page in question here:  http://www.envisionlocal.com/

Underneath the blue, you'll see where there's a blank white space before the grey area starts.  I believe it's this code:

```
<div class="bottom_part"></div>
```

Which uses this CSS:

```
#banner .bottom_part {
    clear: both;
    padding: 167px 0 0;
}
```

But when I remove that from the HTML, I still get the same white space on the page.  Does anyone know what I need to change to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inspect your page.

```
body {
    background: url("../images/body_bg3.jpg") repeat-x scroll left 0 #F3F4F4;
}
```

This is the image: http://www.envisionlocal.com/images/body_bg3.jpg

Your background is one whole image, that gives the impression that there is white space when you remove your div.

Answer (score 0):

Change your background-image:'body_bg3.jpg' in body element

Answer (score 0):

Drip was right, need to fix background image on body.
To fix the issue replace file images/body_bg3.jpg with this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTwFE.jpg
and remove dev with class "bottom_part" from html

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the background image here: http://www.envisionlocal.com/images/body_bg3.jpg

When you zoom in you can see a 1px wide image that is repeated horizontally with this style:

```
background: #F3F4F4 url(../images/body_bg3.jpg) repeat-x left 0px;
```

You can crop the blue part out of the image or mimic the image with a div structure and styling.